# Add additional event binding to Angular child components

Tags: angular

In react to create a parent/children component that has some additional methods bound to the children I have something like the following

```
<RadioGroup
    {...args}
    value={value}
    onChange={(name, value) => setValue(value)}
>
    <Radio value="apple">apple</Radio>
    <Radio value="orange">orange</Radio>
    <Radio value="banana">banana</Radio>
</RadioGroup>
```

```
const key = `${name}-${child.props.value}`;
const _name = `${name}-${Date.now()}`;
return React.cloneElement(child, {
    ...childAttrs,
    name: _name,
    checked: child.props.value === value,
    onChange: onChangeHandler,
    key,
});
```

The Angular component would be build in a similar way

```html
<my-radio-group
    [name]="name"
    [disabled]="disabled"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
    [orientation]="orientation"
>
    <my-radio [value]="'apple'">apple</my-radio>
    <my-radio [value]="'orange'">orange</my-radio>
    <my-radio [value]="'banana'">banana</my-radio>
</my-radio-group>
```

What is the best and simplest way to add an 'onChange' like handler to the child components in Angular? Can this be done without RxJs and subscriptions?

Comment: I didn't get your question, chris. Could you rephrase it? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: It’s an interesting question (probably solvable with @viewChildren) - however, in this example - why would you need event handlers on the children? The parent will catch a change anyway?

Comment: @MikeOne I need to bind to the onChange event within the child html input radio elements. You say the parent will catch a change, I am not that familiar with Angular, could you explain how this is?

Comment: Sure, got it. You can get references to the children from the parent using @ViewChildren and from those get actual (internal) references to their public props. However, the best and easiest solution would probably involve RxJs, even when you would bind to their @ Output event handlers (as they are technically Subjects anyway). Why that limitation?

Comment: And to be more extensive- you really wouldn’t want to set it up this way anyway. I’d really recommend making components to be used in Forms actual form inputs that use ControlValueAccessors. That way you radio components would acts as any form control.

Comment: For more context: https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor